How to sample from a distribution defined by an optimization problem
Is there a way to utilize MCMC (or indeed, any other method) to sample from a distribution that is defined implicitly as the optimal solution to a variational problem without solving the variational problem itself? Specifically, consider a probability distribution $\mu$ that is defined over some compact space $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ as:
$$\mu = \arg \min_{\mu\in \text{Prob}[\Sigma]} F[\mu] $$
I had thought some theory would have been well-developed given the natural identification of $\mu$ with the stationary distribution of an MCMC process and the states with the compact space $\Sigma$. However, a somewhat similar question was posted 7 years ago (here) but with no answers.
